# Javascript regular expression that matches files with particular extension except for some specific filenames

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I want it to match all paths to css files, except for some specific filename (`file.css`):

```
var re = /.../;
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file2.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/e.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/other-file.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file2.css')); // true
```

Then, what if I want to exclude `asdfg.css` as well?

P.S. The question is about cases where you can't write code, only specify regular expression.

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RjCB3m/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd do something like this:

```js
var re = /\/(?!(file|asdfg)\.css$)[^\/]*\.css$/;

console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file2.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/e.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/other-file.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file2.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/asdfg.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file/file2.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.css/file2.css')); // true
```

I regard this as more readable because the list of exclusions is a simple alternation and could easily be extended to include other files without taking other factors (such as their length) into consideration.

The RegExp starts by matching the final `/` in the path (technically that matches any slash but the code that follow ensures there can't be another one). It then checks that none of the excluded files are matched using a negative lookahead. The lookahead needs to be anchored to the end of the string to ensure it doesn't exclude too generously. After the lookahead it simply consumes as many 'non-slashes' as possible (i.e. the file name) and then checks that everything ends with a `.css`.

Comment: The only remark I can make here is that it makes more sense to use `+` instead of `*` here. But that's nothing major.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
var re = /\/(.{0,3}|(?!file).{4}|[^/]{5,})\.css$/;
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/e.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/other-file.css')); // true
```

And for two files:

```
var re = /\/(.{0,3}|(?!file).{4}|(?!asdfg).{5}|[^/]{6,})\.css$/;
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/asdfg.css')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/file.js')); // false
console.log(re.test('/path/to/e.css')); // true
console.log(re.test('/path/to/other-file.css')); // true
```

If you know any better/readable ways, feel free to post your answer.

Comment: Why have you put this as an answer?.  Just edit your original question.

Comment: @Keith Because it answers my question. What's wrong about that? Feel free to post your answer. If it's better, I'll accept it.

Comment: You do know everyone can see your profile, and I've just had a quick look.  It appears you do this often, and then mark you own answer as the accepted answer.  To be frank, I find what your doing slightly distasteful.  I'm not even going to bother giving an answer, because even when people have tried to help you, you have still accepted your own reply.  Anyway, it's up to you, people will judge you on your merits, not the No. next to your name.

Comment: @Keith Feel free to show me my question where I accepted worse answer, and I either explain why you're wrong, or accept the other answer (which is possible, to err is human). Regarding "people trying to help me", if that's their main concern, I pity them. I don't need help. I had a solution before asking the question. But I hope now that we have a better solution, somebody will benefit from it. Then, I can't honestly say, that I don't care about No. next to my name. But I do nothing to increase it other than by asking questions I'm concerned with.

Comment: `I pity them`, That say's it all really.

Comment: @Keith I can hardly imagine such people. Those who are not curious about solving an issue, And maybe even don't like programming. Just trying to help people. So, noone to pity. I meant, that in my opinion the point of the site is sharing ideas. Helping people is but by-product.

Comment: I think it's great your sharing idea's, no problem with that.  But if your not wanting people to answer them, then maybe say that in your initial question.  Otherwise people might read your question, assume you need help, spend time finding a solution for you, only for you to say `I don't need help`.  I hope you can see were I'm coming from, I'm sure you mean well, and I've taking it the wrong way.  Also have you ever thought about a Blog, there great for these sort of things.

Comment: To make it clear, by sharing ideas I meant that one person asks a question, and the other person answers it. In other words, shares a solution or idea. When both are the same person is just a special case. And don't take me wrong, I *do* want people to answer my questions. I just don't feel like accepting any answer. The best solution wins. The best in my opinion, indeed. But that probably can't be helped. Programmers don't always agree.